# MySQL "Deactivated" status in Xampp on Linux Mint

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I start my services like

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

at that time it shows that

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.0…
XAMPP: Starting Apache with SSL (and PHP5)…
XAMPP: Another MySQL daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD…
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

MySQL is not running. How can I fix this?

Comment: There is another mysql already running... you can restart your server and it should work, or just kill mysql process or delete a pid...

Comment: n when i run /xampp/phpmyadmin then this type of error is coming

Comment: i have already reset n same error is coming
n when i run /xampp/phpmyadmin then this type of error is coming

Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Config.class.php on line 755

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linux, try these commands

`cd /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin`

`sudo chmod o-rw config.inc.php`

Source: [Apachefriends Forum](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=196640&sid=598c743686d9307dc859961fe7a87426)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by editing the following line in `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`. line number around 27
username is your lampp folder username or the user that you want to run mysql
`username= your-username`